# How to change the numbering of \subsubsection just *once*?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters, sections-paragraphs, report

`\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}` is my document class.

Chapters’ are usually numbered `1`, `2`, `3`, …

Subsections’ numbers are, thus, usually `1.1`, `1.2`, `2.1`, `2.2`, `2.3`, …

Following this pattern, subsubsections’ numbers are usually `1.1.1`, `1.1.2`, …

---

Now, I have the following problem: There is a chapter with only one subsection. Therefore, I do not want it to be numbered and just wrote:

```
\subsection*{Title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Title}
```

Let’s say this is within chapter `2`. If I now use `\subsection{Step 1}`, this subsection will be numbered as `2.0.1`. But I do not want it to be numbered that way nor to be numbered as `2.1`. I would prefer it to be numbered as `1`, `2`, …

How can I do that?

---

**Edit:** My full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    left=2cm,
    right=2cm,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=2cm,
    bindingoffset=0mm
}
\addto\captionsbritish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Table of contents}%
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \vspace*{2cm}
        \centering
        {\scshape\LARGE Titlepage \par}
    \end{titlepage}

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \tableofcontents

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{One}
    This is chapter one.
    \section{One dot one}
    This is the first section of chapter one.
    \subsection{One dot one dot one}
    This is the first subsection of chapter one.
    \subsection{One dot one dot two}
    This is the second subsection of chapter one.
    \subsubsection{One dot one dot two dot one}
    This is the first subsection of 1.2.
    \subsubsection{One dot one dot two dot two}
    This is the second subsection of 1.2.
    \section{One dot two}
    This is the second section of chapter one.
    \chapter{Two}
    This is chapter two.
    \section{Two dot one}
    This is the first section of chapter two.
    \subsection*{Subsection of chapter two}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Subsection of chapter two}
    This is the only subsection of chapter two. It, thus, does not have any numbering. But it contains two subsections which I do not want to be numbered in the way as described above.
    \subsubsection{Step 1}
    This is the first subsection (= subsubsection) of “Subsection of chapter two”.
    \subsubsection{Step 2}
    This is the second subsection (= subsubsection) of “Subsection of chapter two”.
    \section{Two dot two}
    This is the second section of chapter two.
\end{document}
```

Note that I am also using

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
```

Now, I also see another aesthetical problem, but I do not necessarily need this to be solved. The `Subsection of chapter two` is left aligned with `Two dot one` in the table of contents. Maybe it would be better to indent the `Subsection of chapter two` a bit so that it is aligned with the beginning of the number of the subsubsections.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: If you have only one subsection in a chapter it is no subsection then (It can't be the subsection 2 as well then, according to your numbering scheme)! It may be a section itself or just place it inline. Otherwise use `\begingroup\refstepcounter{subsection}\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}\subsection*{Title}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Title}}\endgroup`

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend such a numbering scheme at all, especially omitting the chapter number will confuse readers.

```
\begingroup
\refstepcounter{subsection}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\subsection*{Subsection of chapter two}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Subsection of chapter two}
This is the only subsection of chapter two. It, thus, does not have any numbering. But it contains two subsections which I do not want to be numbered in the way as described above.
\subsubsection{Step 1}
This is the first subsection (= subsubsection) of “Subsection of chapter two”.
\subsubsection{Step 2}
This is the second subsection (= subsubsection) of “Subsection of chapter two”.
\endgroup
```

-- this will change `\thesubsection` inside a TeX group, i.e. as long it is needed here, including the two subsubsections.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    left=2cm,
    right=2cm,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=2cm,
    bindingoffset=0mm
}
\addto\captionsbritish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Table of contents}%
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \vspace*{2cm}
        \centering
        {\scshape\LARGE Titlepage \par}
    \end{titlepage}

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \tableofcontents

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{One}
    This is chapter one.
    \section{One dot one}
    This is the first section of chapter one.
    \subsection{One dot one dot one}
    This is the first subsection of chapter one.
    \subsection{One dot one dot two}
    This is the second subsection of chapter one.
    \subsubsection{One dot one dot two dot one}
    This is the first subsection of 1.2.
    \subsubsection{One dot one dot two dot two}
    This is the second subsection of 1.2.
    \section{One dot two}
    This is the second section of chapter one.
    \chapter{Two}
    This is chapter two.
    \section{Two dot one}
    This is the first section of chapter two.
    \begingroup
    \refstepcounter{subsection}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
    \subsection*{Subsection of chapter two}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Subsection of chapter two}
    This is the only subsection of chapter two. It, thus, does not have any numbering. But it contains two subsections which I do not want to be numbered in the way as described above.
    \subsubsection{Step 1}
    This is the first subsection (= subsubsection) of “Subsection of chapter two”.
    \subsubsection{Step 2}
    This is the second subsection (= subsubsection) of “Subsection of chapter two”.
    \endgroup
    \section{Two dot two}
    This is the second section of chapter two.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what a “single subsubsection” is supposed to be: you can subdivide something in two or more parts.

If you insist, here is a possibility.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    left=2cm,
    right=2cm,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=2cm,
    bindingoffset=0mm
}
\addto\captionsbritish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Table of contents}%
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \vspace*{2cm}
        \centering
        {\scshape\LARGE Titlepage \par}
    \end{titlepage}

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \tableofcontents

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{One}
    This is chapter one.
    \section{One dot one}
    This is the first section of chapter one.
    \subsection{One dot one dot one}
    This is the first subsection of chapter one.
    \subsection{One dot one dot two}
    This is the second subsection of chapter one.
    \subsubsection{One dot one dot two dot one}
    This is the first subsection of 1.2.
    \subsubsection{One dot one dot two dot two}
    This is the second subsection of 1.2.
    \section{One dot two}
    This is the second section of chapter one.
    \chapter{Two}
    This is chapter two.
    \section{Two dot one}
    This is the first section of chapter two.
    \subsection*{Subsection of chapter two}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Subsection of chapter two}
    This is the only subsection of chapter two. It, thus, does not have any numbering. But it contains two subsections which I do not want to be numbered in the way as described above.
    \subsubsection{Step 1}
    This is the first subsection (= subsubsection) of “Subsection of chapter two”.
    \subsubsection{Step 2}
    This is the second subsection (= subsubsection) of “Subsection of chapter two”.
    \section{Two dot two}
    This is the second section of chapter two.
\end{document}
```

Bear in mind that labels to the special subsubsections should be inside the title:

```
\specialsubsubsection{Step 1\label{step1}}
```